# Wrong view count for questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

I have a question with 1508 views, but in the personal page list it gets reported as 2k.  Bug or aggressive approximation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a bug, this is by design. When you reach 1000 views, the view count is rounded up or down to the nearest thousand. This is why your view count of 1508 is rounded up to 2k.

You will find that the system will round other values as well - reputations over 10k, for example, are rounded to the nearest hundred.

Comment: What the hell !!! This really seems silly to me. To me numbers are an exact thing, and when they are not usually means that they are at least that number (that number OR HIGHER) but the approximate value that SO seems to associate with the viewcount seems rather odd. To display 1508 in one section and 2K in another without any distinct relationship is frustrating. Do badges use the correct value or the "approximate" value?

Comment: To clarify, does this "feature" violate the Principle of least astonishment ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @Nippysaurus I agree it should be showing just the **floor** value, rather than rounded. But their choice was probably, like most of the site, thinking about the big picture and in that case rounding and average suits better. Think 1K showing while there's actually 1.9 or 1.8